# How to configure raspberry pi as wireless router and web server at the same time?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless, pi-4, access-point

I configured my raspberry pi as a wireless access point with a bridge between `eth0` and `wlan` using  [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) but now I can't access it. I'm not quite good with networking, but I think it doesn't currently work because it passes all traffic from `eth0` (where my requests come from) to `wlan`.

I'm asking if there's a way not to send all traffic to `wlan`, so I can also use the machine as a webserver.

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/106673/edit) your question and add the output of this two commands to it: `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I can simply access my webserver through the `wlan0` interface with a little configuration on the access point. I don't quite remember what it was exactly as I tried multiple things, but I believe the solution was to remove `denyinterfaces wlan` from `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. Then you use `ifconfig` to find out what ip address `wlan0` uses, and you use it to connect to your webserver instead of the one associated with the ethernet connection.

Comment: Not very helpful for someone who is looking for a solution. How exactly do you solve the problem?

Comment: I understand, I just edited the answer to add some more information

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set a pseudo interface.  If your eth0 IP address was 192.168.0.1 set up eth0:0 with IP address 192.168.0.2 (or whatever works for your address scheme and DHCP scope), then you should be able to use the 192.168.0.2 IP address for the web service.  For syntax you could refer to https://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-command-examples/.